# Multi Threaded .NET Application inside Service Fabric throwing 'The operation has timed when issuing HttpWebRequests'

Tags: c#, .net, azure-service-fabric

I have built a C# application using .NET Framework 4.7.2. which is being hosted inside Service Fabric.

It is multi-threaded (N=50) where each thread calls third party dll which invokes `Parallel.ForEach` under the hood thus creating 20 tasks per thread. (Degree of Parallelism is configurable as an argument, tried both 3 and 1). Each task is issuing `HttpWebRequest` to the same **remote** host.

It turns out that after some time application starts throwing

```
System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
```

For the majority of threads/tasks.

Afterwards tried simulating same application using LinqPad with:

`ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 2 (Default)`

`ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 1000`

Value of 2 thrown the same "timed out" exception and value of 1000 succeded without any issues.

When the same value has been added to c# application at the Service Fabric initialization part of the service, it logged it has set the limit to the 1000 but later in the runtime started seeing again timed out issues.

Is there any limitation if Service Fabric isn't applying underlying application app configurations when being hosted in the cluster? Got any other idea which could

Comment: How many nodes has your cluster?

Comment: Please add the code around the usage of `WebRequest`